# How to I get sublibrary manifests from uber jar

Tags: java, maven, jar, pom.xml

I'm building an uber jar and I'm trying to pull out the version information of a sub libraries manifest file.  For some reason, the manifest information does not appear in the jar anymore.

This used to be a project built with the war plugin and that worked, however, I can't figure out how to get the same behaviour with the jar plugin.

Here is my configuration currently.  I'm not sure why it no longer works.

How can I pull the library manifest information out or what is going on that is making this not work?

**Executable pom file**

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>package-jar-with-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>com.clearwateranalytics.perseus.worker.PerseusWorker</mainClass>
                                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                                <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                            </manifest>
                            <manifestEntries>
                                <Implementation-Build>${build.number}</Implementation-Build>
                                <Build-Date>${maven.build.timestamp}</Build-Date>
                            </manifestEntries>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

---

**Library pom**

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Implementation-Build>${build.number}</Implementation-Build>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Library method for getting build information**

```
private static String getBuildNumber()
{
    try
    {
        Enumeration<URL> resources = ServerVersionDao.class.getClassLoader().getResources("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
        while (resources.hasMoreElements())
        {
            try
            {
                Manifest manifest = new Manifest(resources.nextElement().openStream());
                Attributes attributes = manifest.getMainAttributes();
                if ("perseus-server-lib".equals(attributes.getValue("Implementation-Title")))
                {
                    String versionNumber = getVersion(ServerVersionDao.class);
                    String buildNumber = attributes.getValue("Implementation-Build");
                    String build = "";
                    if (versionNumber != null)
                        build += versionNumber;
                    if (buildNumber != null)
                        build += " b" + buildNumber;

                    if (!build.trim().isEmpty())
                        return build;
                }
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException("Got here!!!!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello I dont think you can add the individual MANIFESTs as you expect. The classes are just included in the uber-jar, not as jars but as packages.

BUT in case you want to retrieve the version of this specific library that is one of the dependencies (right?), you can eventually follow a similar pattern as your code above, but instead of trying to load the generated META-INF/MANIFEST, you can find versioning information of the included dependencies, close by ;)

```
META-INF\maven\group-id/artifact\pom.properties
```

e.g

```
META-INF\maven\perseus/perseus-serverlib\pom.properties
```

Give it a try :)

In there you can find a property file like the following:

```
#Generated by Maven
#Sun Aug 02 13:18:09 PDT 2015
version=1.8.3
groupId=org.jsoup
artifactId=jsoup
```